# Disable graphic accelleration on CentOS 7 - Mesa Libraries

Tags: opengl, 3d, centos7, graphic, mesa

I have finally successfully compiled a Qt app (C++) using OpenGL on a CentOS 7 machine. The application was originally developed for Windows.

I have an OpenGL scene that is showing a black screen. It works if I compile the project with the Windows version of Qt in a Windows environment.

All controls and functionalities are working except I cannot see the result on the OpenGl scene. After few searches, I have discovered it might be a 3D acceleration problem and I have been advised to try to disable it.

I am using the Mesa libraries on a CentOS system:

```
glxinfo | grep vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
```

and I can see the that 3D acceleration is on:

```
glxinfo | grep rendering
direct rendering: Yes
```

How do I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use environment variable `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`. It disables hardware acceleration. From Mesa3D documentation:

> LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE - if set, always use software rendering